# How do I make Attachments View only show Title with Attachments?

Tags: custom-list

In SharePoint 13 I created a Custom List. I added a resume to one of the List Items. What would I do in order to make the Attachments View ONLY show the Title that has the List with the Resume attachment to it? When I select the Attachments List it shows the paperclip attachment in the Lists at the top, however, it also shows the other Lists. I would like only the list with the Attachment to show.

Thanks

Comment: means ? You want to show only those items of the list who have attachments ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the new View.

- Go to *List Settings > Create View*
- In *Filter* > Set Attachments *is not equal to* No

[image]

Now, in this view you will able to see only those items which have attachments.

CAML Query for the view will be:

```
<Query>    
    <Where>
      <Neq>
        <FieldRef
          Name="Attachments" />
        <Value
          Type="Attachments">1</Value>
      </Neq>
    </Where>
</Query>
```